# How to draw charts without displaying it's data in the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm trying to display charts in a Google Sheet using Google App Script.

It appears to me that the only way to feed data to a chart is through displaying this data on a sheet and passing the data's range to the chart. As such:

```
var chart = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().newChart().asPieChart()
    .addRange(range)
    .build();

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertChart(chart);
```

Where **range** is a range in the sheet holding the chart's data.

My question is if there is a way to display the chart without having to display it's raw data as such ?

Comment: Hacky solution and depends on why you need the data hidden but you could use the data range from a second worksheet and then hide the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about these workarounds? I couldn't find how to create charts without range of spreadsheet for EmbeddedChartBuilder. So I thought other 2 workarounds.

### Workaround 1

In this case, in order to display no data for charts, it uses a range of other spreadsheet.

```
var id = "### spreadsheet id ###"; // There is data in this spreadsheet.
var name = "### sheet name ###";
var datarange = "### data range ###";
var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name).getRange(datarange);
var chart = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().newChart().asPieChart()
  .addRange(range)
  .build();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertChart(chart);
```

### Workaround 2

In this case, in order to display no data for charts, it reads data using `newDataTable()`. You can add your data to `newDataTable()`.

The created chart is imported to spreadsheet as an image. The chart sample is from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts).

```
var data = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, 'Month')
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'In Store')
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, 'Online')
    .addRow(['January', 10, 1])
    .addRow(['February', 12, 1])
    .addRow(['March', 20, 2])
    .addRow(['April', 25, 3])
    .addRow(['May', 30, 4])
    .build();

var chart = Charts.newAreaChart()
    .setDataTable(data)
    .setStacked()
    .setRange(0, 40)
    .setTitle('Sales per Month')
    .build().getBlob();

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().insertImage(chart, 1, 1);
```

### References :

- [EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)
- [Charts Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/)

If these are not useful for you, I'm sorry.